# Cannot invoke filter with an argument list of type ((_) -> _)

Tags: ios, swift

Im trying to filter by title. Im getting this error
[image]

```
class Incident {
    var title: String = ""
}

if sender.text != "" {
    self.incidents = incidents.filter { $0.title.rangeOfString(sender.text, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch) == "hola" }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Post the exception as plain text.  Screenshot is option, but you should definitely have the plain text in there, for multiple reasons....

Comment: `rangeOfString(...) == "hola"` makes no sense as rangeOfString returns an (optional) range, not a string. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Filter titles wich have the word hola

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rangeOfString()` returns an optional range which is `nil` if the
string was not found. To filter all objects whose `title` contains
the string "hola" it should be (untested):

```
self.incidents = incidents.filter {
    $0.title.rangeOfString("hola", options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch) != nil
}
```